# Dados não são exibidos na tabela pelo AbstractTableModel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de solicitação de passagens, porém por ter que adicionar um `JXDataPicker` na tabela, eu tive que implementar o `AbstractTableModel`.

O modelo aparentemente está de acordo com a documentação, consigo exibir todos os campos, porém não consigo ver os dados, a linha aparece, porém nada de informação.

Essa é a configuração do modelo.

```
public class PassagemTableModel extends AbstractTableModel{

    private ArrayList<PassagemAerea> passagem;
    private final String[] colunas = {"Data de Partida", "Data de Retorno", "Aer. de Partida", "Aer. de Retorno", "Horário de Chegada No Local", "Horário de Saída do Local","Tipo de Bagagem"};
    private final Class[] columnClass = new Class[] {
        Date.class, Date.class, String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class
    };

    public PassagemTableModel(){
        this.passagem = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void adicionaPassagem(PassagemAerea passagem){
        this.passagem.add(passagem);
        fireTableDataChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount(){
        return passagem.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex){
        return columnClass[columnIndex];
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
            return colunas[columnIndex];
    }


    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return colunas.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {

        switch(columnIndex)
        {
            case 0: passagem.get(rowIndex).getDataPartida();
            case 1: passagem.get(rowIndex).getDataVolta();
            case 2: passagem.get(rowIndex).getAeroportoSaida();
            case 3: passagem.get(rowIndex).getAeroportoRetorno();
            case 4: passagem.get(rowIndex).getHorarioChegada();
            case 5: passagem.get(rowIndex).getHorarioSaida();
            case 6: passagem.get(rowIndex).getTipoBagagem();
            default: return null;
        }
    }

     @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object Value,int numLin, int numCol) {

        switch(numCol){
            case 0:
               passagem.get(numLin).setDataPartida((Date)Value);
               break;
            case 1:
               passagem.get(numLin).setDataVolta((Date)Value);
               break;
            case 2:
               passagem.get(numLin).setAeroportoSaida(Value.toString());
               break;
            case 3:
               passagem.get(numLin).setAeroportoRetorno(Value.toString());
               break;
            case 4:
               passagem.get(numLin).setHorarioChegada(Value.toString());
               break;
            case 5:
               passagem.get(numLin).setHorarioSaida(Value.toString());
               break;
            case 6:
                passagem.get(numLin).setTipoBagagem(Value.toString());
                break;
        }
        fireTableDataChanged();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Aqui segue a chamada do modelo no construtor da classe que contém a tabela.

```
    initComponents();

    passagemTableModel = new PassagemTableModel();

    tblSolicitacoes.setModel(passagemTableModel);
    tblSolicitacoes.setRowHeight(40);
    tblSolicitacoes.setBackground(Color.red);
    tblSolicitacoes.setSelectionBackground(Color.PINK);

    TableColumn dataPartidaModel = tblSolicitacoes.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
    TableColumn dataRetornoModel = tblSolicitacoes.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
    dataPartidaModel.setCellEditor(new DateCellEditor());
    dataRetornoModel.setCellEditor(new DateCellEditor());
    dataPartidaModel.setCellRenderer(new DateCellRenderer());
    dataRetornoModel.setCellRenderer(new DateCellRenderer());

}
```

No caso a ideia seria o seguinte, existiria um botão que, ao clicar, adicionaria uma linha vazia, para edição do usuário, consigo incluir essa linha normalmente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

porém se eu já incluo valores ela não mostra, mesmo que eu edite, nada acontece. A chamada que preenche ela é essa:

```
 private void encheTable(){
    PassagemAerea pa = new PassagemAerea();

    pa.setAeroportoRetorno("TESTE");
    pa.setAeroportoSaida("TESTE");
    pa.setDataPartida(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    pa.setDataVolta(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    pa.setTipoBagagem("TESTE");
    pa.setHorarioChegada("10");
    pa.setHorarioSaida("TESTE");

    passagemTableModel.adicionaPassagem(pa);
}
```

Como resolver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O método responsável por exibir os dados nas células da tabela é o [`getValueAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html#getValueAt-int-int-) herdado da interface `TableModel`, e se você observar sua assinatura(`Object getValueAt​(int rowIndex, int columnIndex)`) verá que ele retorna `Object`. Este retorno é a informação que será exibida em cada célula da tabela, pois internamente o java chama esse método várias vezes conforme o número de linhas e colunas que a tabela possuir.

Seu método `getValueAt` recupera valores do objeto `Passagem`, mas nada faz com ele, e no final está sempre retornando `null`, pois em nenhum dos cases você retorna informação dos objetos para a tabela. Adicionando um `return` em cada case, as células serão exibidas corretamente:

```
@Override
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {

    switch(columnIndex)
    {
        case 0: return passagem.get(rowIndex).getDataPartida();
        case 1: return passagem.get(rowIndex).getDataVolta();
        case 2: return passagem.get(rowIndex).getAeroportoSaida();
        case 3: return passagem.get(rowIndex).getAeroportoRetorno();
        case 4: return passagem.get(rowIndex).getHorarioChegada();
        case 5: return passagem.get(rowIndex).getHorarioSaida();
        case 6: return passagem.get(rowIndex).getTipoBagagem();
        default: return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado !! Resolvido.

Comment: @JoseAguiar você pode aceitar a resposta clicando no `v` ao lado, assim, a pergunta fica como resolvida e serve de referencia para outros com problema semelhante :)